# 'Cars have almost disappeared. So this car has almost.' : Why 'Division' and not 'Accident'?

Tags: fallacies

<sub>Source: p 174, *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014) by Patrick Hurley</sub>

Abbreviate the Fallacy of Accident to FA and the Fallacy of Division  to FD.

> Just as composition can sometimes be confused with hasty generalization (converse
>   accident), division can sometimes be confused with accident. As with composition,
>   this confusion can occur only when the “whole” is a class. In such a case, division proceeds
>   from the class to the members, whereas accident proceeds from the general to
>   the specific. Thus, if a class statement is mistaken for a general statement, division may
>   be mistaken for accident. To avoid such a mistake, one should analyze the premises of
>   the argument. If the premises contain a general statement, the fallacy committed is accident;
>   but if they contain a class statement, the fallacy is division. Example:
>
> [1.] [The class of] Stanley Steamers have almost disappeared.
>   [2.] This car is a Stanley Steamer.
>   [3.] Therefore, this car has almost disappeared.
>
> The first premise is not a general statement but a class statement. The attribute of having
>   almost disappeared is predicated collectively. Accordingly, the fallacy committed is
>   division, not accident.

I understand the first paragraph (on the general distinction between FA and HD), but I do not comprehend how 1 is a class statement. Why can 1 not be equally interpreted correctly as 4 below?

> [4.] [All individual] Stanley Steamers have almost disappeared.

Comment: Because "disappear", as in "become invisible" (as opposed to "become occluded"), makes no sense for macroscopic solid objects such as cars. Thus it can *only* be class statement, using "disappear" metaphorically (as "decrease in membership").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cars have almost disappeared" means "quite all (the members of the class of cars) have disappeard" while "all" means "all".

Thus, to say that "[The class of] cars have almost disappeared" means that only few of them (the cars) are still running.

"[All] cars have almost disappeared" instead, makes little sense, because it seems to mean that every single car is a sort of "phantom".

---

A similar example is with:

> "There are 67 [Moons of Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Jupiter)";

if we agree, for the sake of discussion, that *numbers* are predicated of *concepts*, the above statement means that the number 67 is a sort of property of the concept "Moon of Jupiter", i.e. the class of Moons of Jupiter has 67 members.

This does not mean that each (individual) Moon of Jupiter **is** 67...

You cannot distribute (or "divide") the property "to be 67" from the collection of Moons to the individual moons belonging to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing structural in this statement that lets you know whether it's a class statement (about a set of things, considered as a group) or a generalization (true in general of the individual things in the group).  Like many other statements in natural language, you need to rely on your knowledge and common sense to make the determination.

In this case, out of the two possible ways of interpreting the statement, only one makes sense.  Once you know what kind of statement it is, you can classify the resulting fallacy based on that information.